# Java thread exercise: Access control to a limited resource not working

Tags: java, multithreading

I have this situation: there is a pizzeria with a various number of customers. The pizzeria prepares a random number of pizzas before open and it has only 10 seats. 
Every customer is a thread. I need to make them eat at the same time while there are free seats. The others wait until there is a free set (and until there are prepared pizzas). I tried this solution, but in this way every customer eat alone. Only when it finished another customer can eat. What's the correct solution?

This method of Pizzeria is called by every Customer thread:

```
public boolean eatPizza(Integer nPizzas){
        if(freeSeats< 1){
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
        }
        if(preparedPizzas == 0)    //Pizzas terminated for this evening
            return false;

        freeSeats--;     
        if(nPizzas > preparedPizzas)
            nPizzas = preparedPizzas;  //if he wants more pizzas than avaiable ones he have to settle
        preparedPizzas-= nPizzas;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);  //Time for eat
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        }
        freeSeats++;
        servedCustomers++;
        servedPizzas+= nPizzas;
        if(preparedPizzas> 0){
            notify();      
        }
        else{
            notifyAll(); //Pizzas are terminated for this evening
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Customer thread:

```
public void run(){
        int wait = (int)(Math.random() * 5000);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(wait);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        }
        nPizzas = (int)(Math.random() * 2 + 1);  //He eats 1 or 2 pizzas random
        if(pizzeria.eatPizza(nPizzas))
            fireEatenEvent();
    }
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: The pizzas are being produced while the customers eat, or just before the shop is opened?

Comment: Can you share implementation of `fireEatenEvent()`?

Answer (score 1):

> I tried this solution, but in this way every customer eat alone. Only when it finished another customer can eat

I see invocations to wait() and notifyAll() without any synchronized block. [You must own the monitor or else you will have an `IllegalMonitorStateException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait()).

Therefore I assume there is a missing synchronized block somewhere, which would explain why it is executed by just a thread at a time.

I would had implemented this [Semaphore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)) mechanism (you are controlling the access to a resource with N positions available) in a bit different way (in this case restraining to basic Java synchronization facilities as in your code).

```
/**
 * Lock for controlling seat adquisition (using primitive synchronization).
 * Might as well use {@link java.util.concurrent.Semaphore}
 */
private final Object seatLock = "seatLock"; 
private int availableSeats = 10; // init as preferred
private int availablePizzas = new Random().nextInt(100);

/** 
 * Invoke before critical section for seat.
 * Similar to {@link java.util.concurrent.Semaphore#acquire()}
 * @throws InterruptedException Thread was interrupted. Might want to finalize in a civilized manner. 
 */
public void acquireSeat() throws InterruptedException {
    synchronized(seatLock) {
        // If no available seats, wait until one is released.
        while (availableSeats <= 0) {
            seatLock.wait();
        }
        availableSeats--;
    }
}

/**
 * Variation of {@link #acquireSeat()} to get available pizzas at the same time.
 * If (availablePizzas == 0) then No seat is acquired.
 * @return Number of pizzas actually acquired, that is min(availablePizzas, requested).
 */
public int acquireSeatAndPizzas(int requested) throws InterruptedException {
    assert requested > 0;
    synchronized(seatLock) {
        // Wait if there is pizza, but no seats.
        while (availablePizzas > 0 && availableSeats <= 0) {
            seatLock.wait();
        }
        if (availablePizzas == 0) {
            seatLock.notify(); // wake up next waiting customer before leaving.
            return 0;
        } else {
            availableSeats--;
            requested = Math.min(availablePizzas, requested);
            availablePizzas -= requested;
            seatLock.notify(); // extra notify, in case many customers left.
            return requested;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Invoke after critical section for seat.
 * Similar to {@link java.util.concurrent.Semaphore#release()}
 * Might want to do in a finally block. Might want to invoke this even on premature return or exception.
 */
public void releaseSeat() {
    synchronized(seatLock) {
        availableSeats++;
        // Once a seat is released, notify a waiting thread.
        // Might as well use #notifyAll() if other threads might be waiting on same lock for different reasons.
        seatLock.notify();
    }
}
```

The customer threads might do something like this

```
try {
//  acquireSeat();
//  try {
    int requestedPizzas = new Random().nextInt(2) + 1;
    int servedPizzas = acquireSeatAndPizzas(requestedPizzas);
    if (servedPizzas > 0) try {
        // @@@ Eat pizza or whatever
    } finally {
        releaseSeat();
    } 
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // Your thread was interrupted (while waiting or elsewhere)
    // @@@ handle here and/or propagate
}
```

**Note1:** As [Andy Brown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32200883/java-thread-exercise-access-control-to-a-limited-resource-not-working/32201240?noredirect=1#comment52291029_32201240) points. You can use [java.util.concurrent.Semaphore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html), which can save you some coding and errors. However an example with basic Java synchronization might be useful in some cases. And the `acquireSeatAndPizzas`(I added after comments) exceeds a simple semaphore functionality.

To this regard, the [answer by Steffen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32202285/1117429) provides already an alternative approach using Java concurrency components (no semaphore, though).

**Note2:** The code above has been modified to check the number of pizzas available. It has become not trivial and did not test it (and even if I did it could never be thorough enough). Trust it at your own risk.

Comment: Why not just use a Java Semaphore instead of writing your own (which is a particularly hard thing to do properly - your last paragraph suggests different approaches with several problems of their own)?

Comment: I think you should update your code. Your answer isn't here to show you know how to write a `Semaphore` (or not), nor to encourage new users to program as if they were using Java before 1.5. We are now on Java 8: you would *never* do this now - it is far too easy to get wrong: for example, in your code the `seatLock` and `availableSeats` variables should be immutable, and so `final`, and you don't consider the (complex question of) fairness. `java.util.concurrent.Semaphore` is there to be used for exactly this, and it even comes with timeouts on `acquire`.

Comment: @AndyBrown Thanks for feedback. Answer edited. I still see the point in a basic synchronization answer. Removed my obsolete previous comment (added to main answer). The counter `availableSeats` is mutable, I wouldn't make it final.

Comment: `availableSeats` is mutable, you are right, I'm not sure how I managed to add that to the comment about `seatLock` - apologies.

Answer (score 1):

I created a simple example using an [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) and a [`BlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html).
This way you don't have to handle any locks on your own.

```
public class Restaurant {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final Random rnd = new Random();
        // The queue from which the pizzas are taken
        final BlockingQueue<Pizza> pizzas = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
        // The threadpool that represents the seats of the restaurant
        // 10 customers are handled at one time
        final ExecutorService seats = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        final int nPizzas = rnd.nextInt(50);
        final int nCustomers = rnd.nextInt(100);

        System.out.println("There are " + nPizzas + " pizzas for " + nCustomers + " customers.");

        // Put some pizzas into the queue
        for (int i = 1; i < nPizzas + 1; i++) {
            pizzas.put(new Pizza("Pizza " + i));
        }

        // Marks the end of the queue
        pizzas.put(new PoisonPizza());

        // Create some customers and send them to the restaurant
        for (int i = 1; i < nCustomers + 1; i++) {
            seats.submit(new Customer("Customer " + i, pizzas));
        }

        // Knock off when all customers are gone
        seats.shutdown();
    }

    private static class Pizza {

        private String name;

        public Pizza() {}

        public Pizza(final String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

    }

    private static class PoisonPizza extends Pizza {

        public PoisonPizza() {
            super("PoisonPizza");
        }

    }

    private static class Customer implements Runnable {

        private String name;

        private BlockingQueue<Pizza> pizzas;

        public Customer() {}

        public Customer(final String name, final BlockingQueue<Pizza> pizzas) {
            this.name = name;
            this.pizzas = pizzas;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public BlockingQueue<Pizza> getPizzas() {
            return pizzas;
        }

        public void setPizzas(final BlockingQueue<Pizza> pizzas) {
            this.pizzas = pizzas;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                // Order a pizza
                final Pizza pizza = pizzas.take();

                // Leave the restaurant if all pizzas have been aten
                if (pizza instanceof PoisonPizza) {
                    pizzas.put(pizza);
                    System.out.println(name + ": I'm so hungry.");

                    return;
                }

                // Eat the pizza
                System.out.println(name + ": " + pizza.getName() + " was delicious!");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return;
            }
        }

    }

}
```